# Is it somehow possible to insert an EditorArea into a View in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: view, editor, eclipse-rcp

Is it somehow possible to insert an EditorArea into a View in Eclipse RCP?
I would like to define a restricted area, inside of which the Editors may be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily - in general, there is 'one' EditorArea for an Eclipse application.

You could use a custom [presentation layer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_Custom_Look_and_Feel) to put that EditorArea over one of your views, but that would be it.

A potential (high-level) solution would likely involve passing an `EditorPart` instance to a custom view, which will then call `createPartControl` to render the editor contents inside the view, and manage any necessary initialization of the editor.

Since this editor would be a child control of the view, you might also need to do special hookups for selection/editorsite/actionbars/shortcut keys, etc, so that they continue to work when that editor is being run from within the view.